# ssh not working on OpenVPN configured client and servier

Tags: ssh, openvpn

I have an embedded board (NXP iMX6 sabrelite) that is attached to an LTE stick and runs an openvpn service which configures an interface (tap0) with a local IP address. The same is done for an Ubuntu running PC.  The idea is to have an Ubuntu PC and the iMX6 board, exchange some data via a UDP-RTP application. 
Now I have the following interfaces on imx6 and Ubuntu PC:

on imx6 :

```
eth1: //LTE stick
inet 192.168.9.x

tap0: //open vpn configured interface
inet 192.168.2.222
```

on Ubuntu PC:

```
enx64d1a34bd419: //LTE router
inet 192.168.1.x

tap0: //open vpn configured interface
inet 192.168.2.221
```

The configuration file is specified [here](https://pastebin.com/buWw3E5D).

The configuration files for iMX6 and Ubuntu are the same except the difference in the `cert` and `key` accordingly.

Now the actual problem is I cannot do an ssh to the imx6 board from the Ubuntu PC.

```
root@linux-GP60-2PE:/home/linux# ssh debian@192.168.2.222
ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.222 port 22: No route to host
```

I can ping to the imx6 board, but not ssh. 
I see a number of questions that pertain to be able to ping and not ssh, but in my particualar seems to be an issue with the MTU configuration, and the openvpn configuration.

I can do an ssh with any other interface like ethernet or wifi, but not with the `tap` interface configured to the imx6 device.

Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong with this?

EDIT:
Further debugging on the iMX6 board, using `journalctl _COMM=sshd`, I found the following logs:

```
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1182]: debug1: Forked child 1318.
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: Connection from 192.168.2.221 port 51066 on 192.168.2.222 port 22
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u5
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug2: Network child is on pid 1319
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 106/65534 [preauth]
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Feb 15 03:19:09 stretch-dev sshd[1318]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
```

And then it blocks, with no further logs. And the following line after some time :

```
root@linux-GP60-2PE:/home/linux# ssh debian@192.168.2.222
Connection closed by 192.168.2.222 port 22
```

Comment: If you firewall on your server opened for your VPN IP Range? Is your VPN using IPv4 and not IPv6?

Comment: @Delirium I have disabled the firewall on both systems using `ufw disable`. I am not sure about the VPN using IPv4 or v6. I do get assigned a IPv4 address for the `tap` interface. How do I check this?

Comment: It's not about VPN but about your internet connection setup, disable IPv6 and let your traffic go only with IPv4

Comment: @Delirium I tried disabling the IPv6 as mentioned [here](https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-linuxubuntu) on both iMX6 and Ubuntu PC. It didn't help, the issue still exists.